# Error al convertir String a int en Python

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente código:

```
archivo_a_procesar=open('../input/20220620_v2.csv','r')
archivo_a_generar=open('../output/generado.txt','a')

for line in archivo_a_procesar:
    datos=line.split(",")
    dias_alta_ca=int(datos[3])
    suscr_activa_fl=datos[4]
    if dias_alta_ca>=70 and suscr_activa_fl=='S':
        archivo_a_generar.write(line+'\n')

archivo_a_generar.close()
archivo_a_procesar.close()
```

el archivo que tengo que procesar tiene este formato:

```
10007115,5007036179,2022-06-15,21,S
10009501,5006832928,2022-06-08,28,S
10037368,5006809534,2022-06-07,29,S
10098926,5008171300,2022-05-31,36,S
10118794,5007858292,2022-06-01,35,S
10130197,5007491889,2022-06-08,28,S
10138300,5008352108,2022-06-15,70,S
10163974,5008062621,2022-06-15,21,S
10185625,5007820131,2022-06-11,25,S
10208985,5007271427,2022-05-23,44,S
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto me da el siguiente error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dias_alta_ca'`

No termino de entender por que.
Alguna sugerencia para convertir esa columna a int.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira la primera línea del .csv. Lo más probable es que traiga un header con los nombres de las columnas y luego los datos mismos. Tendrías que abrir el archivo, saltar la primera línea y procesar el resto.

Comment: Ah es cierto!!!, el encabezado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En lo posible no uses split para separar csvs, eso no cubre el caso de que, por ejemplo, una cadena esté entre comillas. Te recomiendo usar el modulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/csv.html) que es parte de la librería estandar (viene con Python).